# How to use MaxMind GeoIP detection while using CloudFlare?

Tags: geoip, cloudflare, maxmind

I'd like to know how can we detect the IP of the client with maxmind GeoIP while using Cloudflare ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use CF special server variable "HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP" to get the actual user IP address.

Please use the following code to replace your original server variable "HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP".

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```